# Error :java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json, http

In my project I am posting json values to my server using the http POST method. But while posting I am getting this error message:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.1.7.95:2403/beacons
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
W/System.err:     at com.beaconsapptwo.estimote.NetworkMgr.callPostMethod(NetworkMgr.java:110)
W/System.err:     at com.beaconsapptwo.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:235)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My PostMethod is this:

```
 public static String callPostMethod(String urlString ,String Json){
 Log.d(TAG,"URL going to call " + urlString + ":::"+Json );
  HttpURLConnection httpcon;
  URL url = null;
  String result = null;
  try{

  url = new URL(urlString.toString());
  httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
  httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
  httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
  httpcon.connect();

  //Write         
  OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
  writer.write(Json);
  writer.close();
  os.close();

  //Read      
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

  String line = null; 
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();         

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
       sb.append(line); 
  }       

  br.close();  
  result = sb.toString();

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 
    return result;
 }
```

This is the Json data:

```
    {
    "uuid": "B9402F30-F5F8-466E-AFI9-25556B57FE6D",
    "minor": "43406",
    "major": "23236",
    "title": "Virtual Beacon",
    "message": "Virtual Beacon message"
    }
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: http://10.1.7.95:2403/beacons doesnt exits

Comment: no it does exit  it is our local server

Comment: error comes to this line  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

Comment: major readibility fixes

Answer (score 0):

You never set your `HttpURLConnection` to allow input. Try setting `httpcon.setDoInput(true);` in your `HttpURLConnection` settings.

Also, you might try removing the line `httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");` Calling `httpcon.setDoOutput(true);` already defaults your connection method to POST, and is therefore unneeded. Plus, `setRequestMethod()` is used for other settings according to the docs:

> HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. It will use POST if
>   setDoOutput(true) has been called. Other HTTP methods (OPTIONS, HEAD,
>   PUT, DELETE and TRACE) can be used with setRequestMethod(String).

Comment: error comes to this line BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpcon.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

Comment: Try removing the line `httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");` You don't need that line because `httpcon.setDoOutput(true);` already defaults to POST. And as the docs state: "Other HTTP methods (OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, DELETE and TRACE) can be used with setRequestMethod(String)."