# POSt request to web API server (InputStream error in android studio)

Tags: android, json, post, request, inputstream

I'm trying to add users' registeration data to a web api server but when I click on  register button in UI after entering the data , the android monitor shows this error :

```
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
```

*this is my code :
----> the onClick function for registeration button :

```
 public void register_register(View view) {
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Email = email.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    // make object from user to insert data
    User user = new User(Name, Email, Password);
    //convert data from user object to a json object
    JSONObject jUser = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray aUser = new JSONArray();
    try {
        jUser.put("Name", user.name);
        jUser.put("Email", user.email);
        jUser.put("Password", user.password);
        //inserting JSON object inside JSON array
        aUser.put(jUser);
        Log.i("my Json object", jUser.toString());
        Log.i("my Json array", aUser.toString());

        String jsonData = aUser.toString();
        new DoRegister().execute(jsonData);

        //clear all edit texts
        name.getText().clear();
        email.getText().clear();
        password.getText().clear();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

-------> this is my posting class that extends from AsyncTask :

```
class DoRegister extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String jsonData = params[0];


        try {

            URL url = new URL(API);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            //send data
            OutputStream   dos = connection.getOutputStream();
            dos.write(jsonData.getBytes());

                //receive & read data response
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                String result = "";
                int byteCharacter;
                while ((byteCharacter = is.read()) != -1) {
                    result += (char) byteCharacter;
                }
                Log.i("my Json api" , "here :" + result);
                is.close();
                dos.close();
                connection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Done" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

------> This is what being shown in android monitor

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://(my api here)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
at com.example.heshamadawy.registeration.RegisterActivity$DoRegister.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:102)
 at com.example.heshamadawy.registeration.RegisterActivity$DoRegister.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:78)
```

Please help me and thank you guys :)

Comment: did you add Internet Permission in manifest

Comment: yes , I added Internet Permission ..and when I click on the doInBackground error in android monitor , it refers to the line :  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

Comment: Please add your stack trace here

Comment: `the android monitor shows this error :` That isn't an error. Which error would that be? Look in the logcat to find the error. Or log the e.getMessage() in catch blocks.

Comment: After `dos.write(jsonData.getBytes());` you should add a `dos.flush();`

Comment: I have added dos.flush() but still have the same exception in logcat.. I have added what I see in android monitor at the end of my question @greenapps ..

Comment: I have added what I see in android monitor at the end of my question @MaharithAdityaSS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649540/filenotfoundexception-at-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343161/error-java-io-filenotfoundexception

Comment: thank you for your help .. I'll try these codes and see @MaharithAdityaSS

Answer (score 1):

ok , I changed my code to Volley library and everything is okay right now ..

If you had the same problem try to use Volley , it's simple ,easy and better

best wishes for you all :)